# $http.post -> start (for preloader)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, http

In my controller I now have:

```
$http.post('/api/agendainsert', { appointment_datetime: appointment_date + appointment_hour, profile: profile, column_id: column_id })
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                $state.go('form.success');
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("Data: " + data +
                    "<hr />status: " + status +
                    "<hr />headers: " + headers +
                    "<hr />config: " + config);
        });
    };
```

Is there a function that I can use when the **$http.post** **STARTS**? So I can **show** a preloader on my screen and **hide** it when the data is successful pulled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a Service to do that. Consider creating a `WaitService`. WaitService will listen for two event `wait:start` and `wait:stop`.

When `wait:start` come you have to use a directive to inject a loading animation on your `<body>`. When `wait:stop` come then you have to remove that loading animation. You can watch for these events in `$rootScope`.

Now include this `WaitService` in your application and use like this.

```
$scope.$emit('wait:start'); //indicate start loading
$http.post('/api/agendainsert', { appointment_datetime: appointment_date + appointment_hour, profile: profile, column_id: column_id })
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                $scope.$emit('wait:stop'); //indicate remove loading
                $state.go('form.success');
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.$emit('wait:stop'); //indicate remove loading
                console.log("Data: " + data +
                    "<hr />status: " + status +
                    "<hr />headers: " + headers +
                    "<hr />config: " + config);
        });
    };
```